# Retrieve the attributes from an object in jquery - works with selectors but not using an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, attributes, selector

```
$(document).bind("insertListener", function(event, elem, param1, param2) {

alert($($(elem)+[attr_a][attr_b!=y]));
});
```

Can't get to alert a true or false there.

elem is the object, I know how the code above would work with an id, or with a class name as the selector:

```
$(".selector[attr_a][attr_b!=y]")
```

But if the selector is the object how would the syntax go. Sorry if this is too simple, cannot figure it out myself and don't find the proper documentation. I also tried using other syntax but it didn't work.

```
$(elem[attr_a][attr_b!=y]);
$($(elem)[attr_a][attr_b!=y]);
elem[attr_a][attr_b!=y];
```

Comment: Try: `alert( $(elem +'[attr_a][attr_b!=y]').length )`;

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(elem).is('[attr_a][attr_b!=y]')
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FMpaE/1)

[`.is()` Reference](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var elem = {
    "id" : "myImage"
};

var sel = '#' + elem.id + '[attr_a][attr_b!=y]'  ; // Assuming it is an ID

alert($(sel));
```

OR

```
 var sel = '#' + elem.id ;

 alert( $(sel).filter('[attr_a][attr_b!=y]')) ;
```